# ring/compojure without jetty

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

I know it's possible to create a war file using `lein ring war`, but it seems to still include jetty dependencies. Is there a way to exclude the jetty dependencies when I'm building the war  (and deploying on tomcat)?

If I can't does this matter at all or is it just extra jars/class files that are packaged up into the war but never actually used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leinigen supports :exclusions in a dependency.

```lisp
(defproject my-project "1.0.0"
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                    [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]
     :dev-dependencies [[autodoc "0.7.1" :exclusions [org.apache.ant/ant]]])
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802026/how-do-i-exclude-jars-from-a-leiningen-project) for details.

Often the problem is working out where the dependencies are coming from. In maven you can do this:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to get a useful ASCII art representation of the dependency tree.

One option would be to generate a pom.xml for your project using

```
lein pom
```

Then runing maven over that.

Comment: Leiningen now has the ability to directly print dependency trees with `lein deps :tree`. No more Maven poms!