# How to specify Heroku Clojure version?

Tags: heroku, clojure

How do I tell Heroku to use a specific version of Clojure?

The sparse (and mostly out-dated) [Heroku Clojure documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-support#supported-clojure-versions) only mentions:

> Heroku supports apps on any production release of Clojure, running on a supported JDK version.

But not how to set the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uberjar build artifact will include the clojure version specified in your project.clj. So just make sure this compatible with the JDK version.

Comment: Thanks, the reason for this question stems from an exception, which I thought was related to version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297427/clojure-and-spec-on-heroku-unable-to-resolve-symbol-bigdec - I thought these were unrelated queries.

Comment: Not used Clojure for a while, is the version of Spec you are using bringing in an older version of Clojure? There is an example of exclusions in this unrelated post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802026/how-do-i-exclude-jars-from-a-leiningen-project. Sorry just a guess

Comment: Will comment on that question