# Clojure and Spec on Heroku: "Unable to resolve symbol: bigdec?"

Tags: clojure, specifications

I'm trying to run a Clojure uberjar on Heroku that uses Spec, but it throws:

> 2018-03-15T09:57:33.361093+00:00 app[web.1]:  at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:381)
>   2018-03-15T09:57:33.361140+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:487)
>   2018-03-15T09:57:33.361173+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.(RT.java:336)
>   2018-03-15T09:57:33.361282+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.main.(main.java:20)
>   2018-03-15T09:57:33.361572+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Unable to resolve symbol: bigdec? in this context, compiling:(clojure/spec/gen/alpha.clj:132:4)**

I think this is related to the alpha-ness of Spec, but I don't know which versions I'm supposed to bump.

Answer (score 0):

`bigdec?` was removed before 1.9 got released:

https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2259

Are you using an older version of Spec together with clojure 1.9 proper?

Comment: Resolved by swapping out tonsky's clojure-future-spec for latest version of spec alpha: `org.clojure/spec.alpha {:mvn/version "0.1.143"}`. But now I have a new problem re: metosin/spec-tools throwing "Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: spec must have a qualified name" on Heroku, but not locally.

Comment: When you use clojure 1.9 it pulls in spec.alpha for you. You don't have to explicitly provide a version for it.

Comment: @PetrusTheron Are you running your stuff directly with the clj-cli tools? Why are you mentioning the artifact in that fashion and your original question is about an uberjar (clj-cli is no build tool!). Anyway, you should really try to get the same "build" environment going as in production.  Murphy beeing a bastard, will make things fail, where it is hard to debug.